# How do you configure IIS to support an api-key to for RavenDB?

Tags: ravendb, api-key

I am considering hosting my own RavenDB server and exposing it to the web.  I would like to create an api-key similar to what RavenHQ / AppHarbor uses.  Can anyone point me in the right direction as how to set up IIS to receive the key and authenticate?  Generating the key itself is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RavenDB 2.0, you don't need to do anything to setup things. RavenDB will do everything for you.
You can create keys from the studio.